# Loss of animation during scrolling

Tags: css

Link to the orignal template:

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/

Upon clicking the "Down" arrow, the page gradually moves down to the next section.

I have cloned it and added few of my own sections, however this has caused loss of the smooth transition effect upon clicking the down arrow.

Plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0MV3QzRpJcPWlpuNMDav

```
.btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: In script.js it mentions `// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin` so add the easing plugin before script.js.

Comment: I could have sworn, I had added that library. Anyways thanks.. I would mark your comment as correct if it is in answer form

Comment: Ok I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for scrolling uses `easeInOutExpo` so you need the easing plugin for the effect. You can also remove `easeInOutExpo` from the code if you don't want to add a plugin for just this effect.

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
     var $anchor = $(this);
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo'); 
     event.preventDefault();
});
```